# Azure Traffic Manager's URL shows degraded but End Points returns 200

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I have an API endpoint from Azure services and I tried to set up Azure traffic manager using this endpoint.

The end point looks like this: https://sampleurl.azurewebsites.net and it requires authentication (bearer token to be exact) to access.

Here's the configuration for the traffic manager:

[image]

Here's how I tried to access:

I send a API request to the **traffic manager's URL** directly with a correct bearer token, but it returned "An error occurred while sending the request."

Could someone point me to some direction of what went wrong?

Comment: Can you not set up an endpoint on the host that accepts anonymous requests for the endpoint monitoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traffic manager monitoring status is degraded, this might be caused by those:

- Endpoint monitoring health checks are failing. You could make sure the endpoint is enabled and returns 200. You can follow these official [troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-troubleshooting-degraded#troubleshooting).
- The endpoint is not included in DNS responses and does not receive traffic. Type `ipconfig /flushdns` to flush the DNS resolver cache in Windows PowerShell prompt. Type `nslookup <your Traffic Manager domain name>`to verify the traffic manager setting. Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-testing-settings#check-traffic-manager-profile-using-nslookup-and-ipconfig-in-windows).

Moreover, per [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-faqs#why-am-i-seeing-an-http-error-when-using-traffic-manager), clients connect to the service endpoint directly, not through Traffic Manager. Therefore, any HTTP error you see must be coming from your endpoints.